# C++ memory errors at program exit

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, glibc

I am writing a client-side app that communicates to a server app through sockets. I'm currently experiencing weird behavior where the application finishes running properly, but then I get many lines like the following thrown on the screen afterwards.

```
*** glibc detected *** ./sll_client: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000787720 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x78a8f)[0x7f9e9cbb5a8f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x73)[0x7f9e9cbb98e3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsD1Ev+0x39)[0x7f9e9d409019]

======= Memory map: ========

7f9e9d893000-7f9e9d895000 rw-p 00021000 07:00 7473                       /lib/x86_64-linux-    gnu/ld-2.13.so
7fff68119000-7fff6813a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff68167000-7fff68168000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted
```

The specific "glibc" error is different nearly every time.

I've already run the application through Valgrind and there are almost no memory leaks detected. The ones that are there don't seem to cause any problems. Is there a general cause of this problem? I could post some code, but its over three thousand lines of C++ and this is the first time in three weeks that this problem has come up.

[Valgrind Output](http://pastebin.com/vKKd80Kv)

[GDB Output](http://pastebin.com/XDfiNNcP)

Comment: Does valgrind report any other problems besides memory leaks?

Comment: I'll say it's finished running properly... it's clearly running improperly now.

Comment: @Fred: I've added a link to the log from Valgrind

Comment: @Ben: Valid, but it still does everything I want. The only problem is that it spits out these additional messages after doing its job :).

Comment: I actually don't have that much experience reading valgrind output, but I'm seeing some "invalid read" and "invalid write" messages. I'd take a look at RCFour.cpp, lines 71-72. I suspect you have a bad pointer there or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The invalid writes of size 4 are almost certainly what's causing your problem. You're stomping on memory you don't own, most likely just before or just after a region of memory that's been dynamically allocated.

The invalid reads of size 4 are problematic too, but aren't causing the output you're getting. Fix them anyway though. :-)

Memory errors can be a huge pain because their effects can show up a long way from where the problem really is. That's part of what tools like Valgrind are for. Memory leak detection is actually a minor feature.

Comment: Those errors point to places where I call to std::swap. It is being called on a populated vector and the indices are valid. Why might that cause an issue?

Comment: @XBigTK12X: That is very odd. I don't know why that would be. Do the values being swapped have their own copy constructors and/or assignment operators?

Comment: The swap is being called on two elements in an std::vector<int>.

Comment: @XBigTK13X: Something like this: `::std::swap(v[x], v[y])`? Are you sure that `x` and `y` are always less than `v.size()`? Maybe one of them ends up going off the end of the vector. The fact the invalid reads and writes are exactly 4 bytes in size would make a lot of sense then, since that's how big an `int` is.

Comment: The bounds of the vector are valid, I tested various cases and was always greeted with valid output.

Comment: @XBigTK13X: Getting valid output isn't the test. Before the `::std::swap` call put in `assert(x < v.size() && y < v.size());`. Of course, don't use `x` and `y` there, but whatever expression you are using in your swap call.

Comment: @XBigTK13X: Did you get an assert failures?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tracked the root cause of `Invalid read of size 4` message that keeps occurring in your valgrind logs??
Those invalid reads are the root cause of your problem.

Comment: This is occurring when I call std::swap on two elements in a vector. Any idea why that might cause a problem?